# Know a story where people investigate a mysterious light?

Tags: story-identification

In the story people are sucked away for reasons they don't know, there is a light and one goes to investigate (and if I remember correctly goes missing?) At the end it is revealed that they are actually fleas that someone is messing with on their pet. I can't seem to remember the name or author. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: The bit about fleas is probably unique, but can you think of any other details?

Comment: If I remember correctly, the main character is a young man and another young girl in involved. They just recently moved to the planet where the strange happening takes place. The man who heads up to investigate the light might be the main character's father but I don't remember well enough to be certain. I believe the main characters parents are scientists.

Comment: The people who investigate a mysterious light and get sucked away turn out to be fleas on someone's pet? And they are also scientists who moved to a new planet? I have a feeling that I missed something. Could you please go over that more slowly?

Comment: @user14111 The story is told in such a way that we readers are lead to believe that the main characters are- hey, what's that whooshing sound?

Comment: @Valorum: Sentient fleas that actively ponder problems and consciously explore the world around themselves isn't fantasy-like enough to you?

Answer (score 5):

Could this be Terry Pratchett's [The Carpet People](http://www.terrypratchettbooks.com/book/the-carpet-people/)? The protagonists are not actually fleas, but they are flea-sized; they don't live on a pet, but on a carpet; but the concept sounds similar, with the "being sucked away" by a vacuum (or something similar) being a central plot point.

> The story follows the journey of a tribe called the Munrungs, across a world known as the Carpet. ... The Munrungs cross the carpet to find a new home after their village is destroyed by the powerful and mysterious natural force Fray. The origins of Fray are never explained in the book, but it is described in a way to suggest sweeping or vacuuming (some reviewers have suggested it represents human footfalls), and is referred to as sweeping on the back cover of the current UK edition...

--[Wikipedia link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Carpet_People)

Comment: I don't believe that is it